# Can a select query cause high write IOPs?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a AWS RDS mysql database, which every so often hangs from what appears to be high write IOPs and high write latency. During these times, we dont believe that we are doing any heavy DB writing.

I have a theory though that one of our select queries may be creating large temp tables because we run aggregation queries which have a large number of keys. ie we run a query over several million rows, with grouping, and the result can have a hundred thousand rows.

Is it possible that we are hitting memory limits on the selects aggregation, and that is causing disk writes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very possible. I have observed temp tables so large that when 4-5 queries were running concurrently, it used up all available disk space on the volume where the MySQL `tmpdir` was pointing.

You can use EXPLAIN to find out if a given query plans to use a temp table, but that doesn't tell you if it's going to be in RAM or on disk. That won't be known by the EXPLAIN, it'll only be known as the query executes and discovers how much data are actually added to the temp table.

You can run `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Created_tmp_%tables'` before and after executing the query (not EXPLAIN, but actually run the query). You'll see if the count of temp tables goes up, and whether the count of temp tables on disk goes up. Here's an example output, showing a temp table but not on disk:

```
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 0     |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 1     |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: I know that disk space is not the same as IOPS, but the point is that temp tables can be large and use both space and I/O bandwidth.